# Saving Bitmap as 32bpp doesn't keep transparency

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawing, transparency

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    bmp.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

The question should be clear: why saving to **BMP** trashes transparency to **black**, while saving to **PNG** ***keeps it*** ?

Just to clarify: ***image*** is in **Format8bppIndexed** format and its palette does contain transparent colors (e.g. it draws correctly onto form/picturebox)

Edit: My bad, **Bitmap.Save()** actually saves BMP in ***Format32bppRgb*** format, even though the bitmap format is ***Format32bppArgb***.

Comment: How can image contain transparent pixels if it is 24bpp?

Comment: Sorry for misinformation. It's in Format8bppIndexed format, and its palette has modified colors containing also transparent ones

Comment: The source images are in this format (Format8bppIndexed)... means I have to.

Comment: Could just paint the image on a new 32bppArgb image to convert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because by default the implementation of the **bmp** file format doesn't support transparency while the **png** file format does.

If you want transparency that will be read by other applications you are going to have to use png. The compression algorithms are lossless so you're not going to get artefacts in your image. The file will take up less space on disk too.

Comment: I think technically the BMP format supports alpha channels/32bits, but most implementations(in particular the MS ones) don't support such bitmaps.

Comment: @mnn - that's news to me, but in that case you'd need to include the flags to tell the save that it was 32 bpp.

Comment: I don't know any tools that support alpha channels in .bmp files, although Windows itself is fine with 32bpp alpha bitmaps as HBITMAPs.

Comment: Hate to say, but 32-bit BMP with alpha isn't even supported by latest IrfanView. Also when loading such BMP using Bitmap.FromFile(), it is "degraded" to Format32bppRgb by GDI+. So the only solution is to use PNG.