# can a bmp image format handle transparency

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, glut, soil

I am making this C++ program that has buttons, button containers, chat boxes, etc., and I want to wrap it around by textures.

I want to generate a smooth edge for all the rectangles I made, and I don't want vertex plotting method to do the work for it, since it consumes more CPU usage and not that looks pretty good, and I don't know if it can work with texture coordinates(i.e. *glTexCoord(u, v)* with *glVertex2f(x, y)* w/c should only be 4 since it is a quad)

I use to load textures using **SDL_LoadBMP()** w/c can load only a format of *.bmp*.(I'm not that sure because it says only LoadBMP there).

## So my questions are:

- can a *.bmp* format handle transparency? if so, how to do it?
- can you show me some code samples using [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) to load image of format *.gif* or any other formats that can handle image transparency?
- can a quad handle an irregular/polygons shape like hexagon or star without drawing its background?

## additional question

*how to import a primitive textbox that renders through c++ opengl so I can copy the texts there into clipboard? as for chatting session in my program.

---

I made my own library that draws the text using GL_POINTS and doesn't look good when resizing the window because the points were spread-out. It takes `const char*` for the text to avoid `#include <*string*>` because I want my program to be not dependent on core functions of C++.

So the better solution is to draw it using bitmaps.

Some suggest to draw it using images so I really need the transparency thing because I want it to draw using quad only.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, the bitmap format *does* support transparency.

It depends on the compression method, the default `RGB` method supports 24-bit color, but `BITFIELDS` compression supports 32-bit color (24-bit + alpha channel).

You can read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

I am using it successfully in the Lime project, here is an implementation written in Haxe: https://github.com/openfl/lime/blob/4adb7d638d15612e2542ae3a0ef581a786d21183/src/lime/_internal/format/BMP.hx

Answer (score 1):

This answer only addresses whether a bmp file can handle transparency, and how to load a png file using SOIL, and I think if you look further by inference it shows you how to load a gif file also. According to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28graphic%29), bmp is one file type that supports transparency through an [alpha channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_channel). But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758833/saving-bitmap-as-32bpp-doesnt-keep-transparency) SO article it doesn't. In my own experience I have not found a way to make bmp transparency work. So theoretically 32bit bmp files are supposed to support transparency, but I doubt it. (Maybe I will eat my words?)

Ok, from the [SOIL website](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html), this code tells how to load a png file which handles transparency:

```
/* load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture */
 GLuint tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
 (
       "img.png"
       SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
       SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
       SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB |
       SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
 );
```

Comment: I have found a tutorial site [here](http://www.softcity.com/article/creative/how-to-create-with-photoshop-a-bmp-file-with-transparency/zMTOwEzN) that showing how to add an alpha channel on a bmp image using a photoshop. My bmps were in 24bpp so it has no alpha channel on it. I don't try converting it to 32bpp yet.

Also I have found out that my mipmap function have not the parameters of RGB + A w/c is the alpha (RGBA) , so I'm still have many options to do.

In your code sample, how can I determine the dimensions of the images (w, h)? does SOIL have that function to automatically calculate it?

Comment: also how to determine the size of the buffer to be pass on the last parameter of gluBuild2DMIPMaps ? I have seen some of those but I don't get the idea there
    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*) malloc(w * l * 4);
and that data is to be put on type of void*(?) I'm confused.

I also need to know all the requirements to load an image. thnx

Answer (score 0):

BMP transparency is possible in Photoshop, with a 24 bits depth, at least.
It doesn't appear as an option of "imwrite" in Matlab.